# It is possible add a multi line message below a field in service now?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I'm using a client script to show messages below different fields,
but can't show a multi line message with showFieldMessage().

Is there a way to set this?
Does this support multi line messages?

I've tried:

g_form.showFieldMsg('field', 'line 1 \n line 2, info)

g_form.showFieldMsg('field', 'line 1 \\n line 2, info)

g_form.showFieldMsg('field', 'line 1' + '\n' + 'line 2', info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show a multi-line message, but you can show multiple messages by calling `showFieldMsg` multiple times:

```
g_form.showFieldMsg(fieldname, 'line 1', 'info');
g_form.showFieldMsg(fieldname, 'line 2', 'info');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br>` as a new line
script like this

```
g_form.showFieldMsg('field', 'line 1 <br> line 2, info)
```

Comment: This does not work